# C# RichTextBox lag

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox control on a WPF form. It has `SpellChecking.IsEnabled`  is set to `true` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is set to `auto`, but whenever I type in it it there is a delay before the text appears.

Setting `SpellChecking.IsEnabled` to `false` or `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `disabled` does not stop the lag.

Can anyone suggest a reason why this lag may be occuring, and a possible solution?

Comment: I have a similar problem- even simply creating an empty project. Setting the thread affinity for the process to 1 core only seems to have solved the problem for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give details on your Operating System, hardware, graphic board, or any other thing that maybe related to your performance?

You should turn off unneeded services, anti-virus, and use `StopWatch` to see what is going on.

Comment: My PC is Windows 7 64-bit, AMD phenom II x4 945 (quad core), 4GB DDR3 memory, Nvidia GTX 460 (1gb) running 2 monitors. My antivirus is microsoft security essentails. How would I use stopwatch to see what is going on?